# How 出 + noun + して works in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> ここ最近 出署してない

What exactly is this sentence trying to say? I realise that 出 is supposed to be a verb here, but why is it placed before 署, a noun, and not after? And what is the してない portion trying to represent, by being tied to 署?

Comment: Could you add more context to your question? For example, where did you see this? It would also be helpful to understand your own research efforts.

Comment: I'm surprised I can't find [出署]{しゅっしょ} in any of my dictionaries...

Comment: @Chocolate Me neither. Would you consider it a common word?

Comment: What does this word mean? 'leave the station'?

Comment: @kandyman The other way around.

Comment: Ah I see. Attend the station. What is the usual context? A police officer being in the station to work?

Comment: @Earthliŋ, そうですね、普通に使ってる言葉なので、辞書に載ってるだろうと思いました。広辞苑にも載ってなかったので、意外です。 ＠Kandyman, はい、`A police officer being in the station to work`、その通りだと思います。

Answer (score 5):

We usually use [出署]{しゅっしょ}する to mean "go the police station (to work)" (警察官などが署に出勤すること).

[出署]{しゅっしょ} is a two-kanji compound noun, which we use to mean "going to the police station". And it can be used as a する-verb, which means you can attach する to the noun and it can function as a verb. E.g. [出社]{しゅっしゃ} "going to the office" + する "do" → 出社する "go to the office"

> 「ここ最近 出署してない。」
> "I haven't been to the police station for a while."

してない is the colloquial contracted form of して**い**ない. Here it means "I haven't done (recently)". (It can also mean progressive "I am not doing" depending on context.)

UPDATE:

As commented by @broccoli, 出署する can also be used for visiting all 署, eg [消防署]{しょうぼうしょ} (fire station), [税務署]{ぜいむしょ} (tax office), and [労基署]{ろうきしょ}(=[労働基準監督署]{ろうどうきじゅんかんとくしょ}) (labor inspection office).

Comment: Why isn't this word in the dictionaries? Is it a very new word?

Comment: It can be used for all 署 besides the police stations, namely 消防署 (fire station), 税務署 (tax office), and 労基署 (labor inspection office).

Comment: @kandyman そうですね・・なんででしょうね・・　グーグル検索してみたら結構いろいろ使われてましたが、「少納言」では3件だけ（書籍 文学 1996年, 書籍 文学 2003年, yahooブログ 2008年）でした。誤用だったらどうしよう...

Comment: @bro! そんな気がしてたんですが、確信がなかったです。。

Comment: @Chocolate 確かに警察署以外はほとんど小説にもならないし関係者以外が使う機会はなさそうですもんね。某消防アニメには出るんだろうか…。ちなみに国税庁のページに[こんな](https://www.nta.go.jp/law/jimu-unei/tyousyu/140924/02/02.htm)のが「早急に納付することが困難な滞納者に対しては出署を求め」